# Kivy app works and functions correctly on pc (windows) but force closes after displaying splash icon android

Tags: android, kivy, kivymd

I have made a simple water intake app that the user can input water intake and the app will track it and display it on a progress bar aswell as a label.
This app works perfectly fine on my pc but crashes after the splash icon loading screen on my phone (Redmi note 10)

main py:
ttps://pastebin.com/MvsA7qtp

spec file:
ttps://pastebin.com/vum5pJGV
(add h to ttps)